# can i see what value of pointing NULL pointer?

Tags: c, null

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int *p=NULL;
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("%x",*p );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I can, How?
If I can't, What value in it?

Comment: Mainly It depends on your platform....

Comment: it'd have the value of whatever null is on your platform. null should be treated as "undefined"/"unknown", therefore what you're trying to do makes very little sense.

Comment: One a microcontroller or on some other simple microprocessor you may be able to read that value.

Comment: ...and usually is IPC (Initial Program Counter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot in general dereference a `NULL` pointer, that gives undefined behavior.

That's sort of the point, so this idea is a bit strange.

Note that this doesn't mean that your code won't run on any platform or produce a result, but it still violates the language specification so the result from running it on some particular implementation doesn't matter.